# graphics.getDrawGraphics() high memory consumption

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, graphics2d

I'm having a high memory usage problem with getDrawGraphics() method. It is causing me a "linear" memory consumption. Doing nothing but calling this once every 16 ms (~60fps) from a Thread, I'm going from 30Mb memory usage to over a hundread (increases an average of 100Kb per second. Sometimes, even 1~7Mb). Here is myRepaint() method. And yes, I've put before setIgnoreRepaint(true);

```
public void myRepaint(){
    if(repaintInProgress) return;
    repaintInProgress = true;

    BufferStrategy strategy = getBufferStrategy();
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics();
    /* draw graphics here */
    if(!loadedMap){
        drawMap(graphics);
        loadedMap = true;
    }
    drawTowers(graphics);
    drawCreeps(graphics);
    if(graphics != null) graphics.dispose();
    strategy.show();
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    repaintInProgress = false;
}
```

I tried clearing all lines inside this function. Memory consumption was stable, meaning that this specific method is causing the memory issue. After searching line by line, I figured out that getDrawGraphics() was the source of this problem. So, I tried letting only these 3 lines of code inside myRepaint():

```
BufferStrategy strategy = getBufferStrategy();
Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics();
graphics.dispose();
```

This makes me believe that whether graphics.dispose() is not working or by having 8Gb of RAM, Java is not caring to free this memory. I've triple-double-checked. I'm not instantiating any objects during the method's execution, so there's no reason memory usage would increase. To keep track of it, I'm using Windows Task Manager.

What could be the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Firstly, the use of Task Manager to profile is probably a bad idea. If you're using the Oracle VM, use VisualVM (or Java Mission Control), which will show you a nice graph of memory use over time as well as enable to you profile in more detail.

Comment: I don't get it. VisualVM says I'm using only 7Mb of heap while Task Manager says I'm using over 80Mb. Funny thing is: if I don't use the getDrawGraphics, Task Manager says my application is using only 31Mb. This specific method is making Task Manager tell me I'm using more memory that I'm actually using. So, can I trust VisualVM? If I can, than my problem is solved, though it is really funny window's behaviour